# how to use joomla 3.8 com_api components for login

Tags: api, joomla, login-page

I am new to API. I want to know how to use API for Username/Password to my joomla website login page.

Depending upon login and password i want to access the third party portal.  I downloaded com_api . I dont know how to use it.

Please help me to solve this issue.

I want to use below id/code to my joomla website.

Headers :

Content-Type : application/json

Authorization : Basic *************************

Body :

{
    "refreshToken":"************",
    "userName":"*************",
    "password":"**********"

}

Thanks a lot...

Regards,
Mahalakshmi

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a plugin that will implement the event `onUserAuthenticate` event. In your code, you will check match the username and the password against your 3rd party user database (api) and you will proceed accordingly.

Essentially, the plugin must be an authentication plugin, so take a look at how the `plugins\authentication\gmail` plugin is written.

No need to use `com_api` (at least for what you want to do).